# Looptools - cancel not working

Tags: add-on

I am working with Blender 2.9 and LoopTools Addon (which i like) but cancel does not seem to work. Whenever i change e.g. to circle and tap ctrl-z, it does not go back but just does other weird things...
is this a bug or a feature?

ok, here is a movie, hopefully this helps. I hoped i could cancel the change from the quad to circle so it would be the quad again but it just selects some weird things. I am pretty new to Blender so maybe i make silly mistake... :(
So the Command Z at the end (i am working on a mac, should be ctrl-z on windows to cancel a operation) is my problem

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pcku1wp1zsogc9/0001-4000.avi?dl=0

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Can you be more specific?

Comment: ok, sorry, i will extend my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your video, it seems you have a problem with your hotkeys. CTRL-Z for you is activating the Select More command, which the default hotkey is CTRL-numpad+
Check your keymap, type in "select more" into the search bar and check what it is mapped to. Since you're new to Blender, it might simply be easier to reset your keymapings to default.

[image]